# iPhone: using retain vs autorelease

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Which one of these is better practice?

A) retain and release the object myself later

```
NSMutableArray* array = [[self getArray] retain];
....
[array release];
```

B) autorelease from the function returning the object

```
getArray {
   NSMutableArray* returnedArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
   .....
   return returnedArray;
}
```

Comment: You should not call your method `getX` -- in Cocoa, methods which "get" something take a pointer-to-pointer and return an object by reference; see, e.g., [`-[NSArray getObjects:range:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABBGGHJ).

Comment: Thanks, Josh, glad someone else is pounding on that now.

Comment: Is there a side effect if I have a getX as one of my functions? If not, I don't see what's wrong with it if I'm the only one using my code...

Comment: No one can force you to write code in an specific way, but a good practice will make your code easier to understand, even to you, and avoid confusions, and wondering for hour what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read and follow Apples guidelines on memory [management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i) and [performance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/ManagingMemory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000160i).

Personally I think the reasons for choosing one way over the other:

Using Autorelease pros:

- You can't stuff it up, memory will be freed at some point.  That I like to think of as "falling into the pit of success".

cons:

- Using autorelease a lot may cause you memory problems as lots of objects build up awaiting be released by the autorelease pools.

Using retain/release pros:

- More control when your memory is used/freed.
- On ios apple recommends that you use release instead of autorelease whenever possible to keep the size of the pool small.

cons:

- Like C/C++ malloc/free new/delete you have to be careful to keep them matched up and it is easy to stuff that up, causing memory leaks.
- For member variables you have no choice, retain/release is it.

I think, whichever style you choose comes down to the situation your code is in and choosing the best style based on there pro's and con's.  I don't think there is any one answer to this.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest rule of thumb when it comes to memory management in Objective-C is that you should release anything that you've explicitly allocated (alloc), copied (copy), newed up (new), or retained (retain).

The release should be done within the scope of the aforementioned actions. If you allocate space for an object that is returned by a method, you should autorelease it before returning it. So, given the two options you've provided, B is the recommended practice.

Comment: I have faced the problem in solution you have suggested the .In my application when i used a autorelease with a UIImageView , then whenever i got memory did receive warning the autoreleased object was released even before it was being returned from my fucntion which creted crashing issue for the app ,but then i shifted to the first approach of allocating and then releasing when its done and the issue was solved.I wrote this as i faced the problem earier and if i am  wrong anywhere you can tell me so that i can improve the memory management style.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return an object you have to use the second approach. In all cases where possible you should use the retain-release approach because this uses less memory.

Comment: I would add that it doesn't necessarily use *less* memory, but it lets the runtime know sooner that you're done using an object and that it's safe to remove it from memory.  This would result in the object getting potentially reclaimed *sooner*, making it so that less memory is consumed.

Comment: I agree with @Wayne Hartman. Its about reference count and not less memory.

Comment: In average over time the app uses less memory.

Comment: Can you explain how? There is one alloc and say multiple retains. However if you dont release then there is a leak.

Comment: It's not the average memory usage that is the concern with autorelease, but the peak. If many objects get put into the pool at once, they hang around until the pool is drained; if they are `release`d immediately then (assuming their retain count drops to 0) they are also deallocated immediately. @Praveen

Answer (score 0):

1. If you `new`, `alloc init`, `retain`, or `copy` (NARC) an object, you have to release it.
2. When the name of a method starts with any of those words, it means it's being created for the caller, who has the responsibility to `release` the object when he is done with it.
   Otherwise the method returned is not owned by the caller, and he has to indicate he wants to keep it calling `retain` on the object.
3. If you can choose, don't abuse autorelease when memory is a concern.

Some comments:

- The first rule logically results in the second. Example: if the outcome of a function (the returned object) survives the execution of the function, all the function can do is autorelease the object.
- Unless there is a memory/performance concern, the overhead of automatic memory management is better than the memory leak chances plus the increased developing time.
- Try to retain/release symmetrically. Example: if you retained on init, then release on dealloc. Same for viewDidLoad/viewDidUnload.
- If you use @property(retain) you have to release in dealloc.

Example:

```
 // created with autoreleased, just call retain if you intend to keep it
 NSString *orange = [NSString stringWithString:@"orange"];
 // created for the caller, you'll have to release it when you are done
 NSObject *apple = [NSString initWithString:@"apple"];
```

Comment: Your second rule needs qualification. Methods which are not named according to the first rule should return object that are _not owned_ by the caller; they should not necessarily be autoreleased. Your third rule is inaccurate. The larger amount of memory available on a device running Mac OS makes using `autorelease` more practical, but you should still `release` whenever you can.